# using ACML dgesv

Tags: visual-studio

I have problem in using ACML.
i work in Visual studio 2010

Here is my code, when i start this code
i met a message as "internal errer: invalid thread id"
but, using a "acml_imax2" function has no problem.

please let me what is the problem with my code.

Thanks in advance.
Kim.

===

```
#include "acml.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

int N=4;
int NRHS=1;
double A[16];
int LDA=4;
int IPIV[4];
double B[4];
int LDB=4;
int info=0;

A[0]=1; A[1]=0; A[2]=0; A[3]=0;
A[4]=2; A[5]=1; A[6]=0; A[7]=0;
A[8]=0; A[9]=0; A[10]=1;A[11]=0;
A[12]=0;A[13]=0;A[14]=0;A[15]=1;

B[0]=1;
B[1]=2;
B[2]=3;
B[3]=4; 

for(int i=0; i<4;i++)
    IPIV[i]=1;

for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<4;j++)
    {
        cout<<A[j*4+i]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

dgesv(N, NRHS, A, LDA, IPIV, B, LDB, &info);


cout<<x;
for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
{
    cout<<B[i]<<" ";
}

cout<<"info: "<<info;

return 0;
}
//  int a=10;
//  int b=8;
//  int x=0;
//  x = acml_imax2( a,  b);
```